# Hiveql aggregation :recurrence tests

Tags: aggregate-functions, hiveql

I'm using hive coupled with hadoop.I'm looking for a function (hiveql) which permit to sort a list of customer matching a rule. 
I want to make a condition test during the last consecutive 10 days (colldate). The result expected is a list of only customers (ressourcename) who math this condition : success>=3 during the last 10 days. Every customer has recorded one entry (number of success) by day.
I use the following query but many map reduce are built and this take many time.
I am looking for a way to optimize :

```
            select J1.colldate,J1.ResourceName
            from
            TABLE J1,
            TABLE J2,
            TABLE J3,
            TABLE J4,
            TABLE J5,
            TABLE J6,
            TABLE J7,
            TABLE J8,
            TABLE J9,
            TABLE J10
            WHERE
            J1.ResourceName=J2.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J3.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J4.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J5.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J6.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J7.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J8.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J9.ResourceName
            and J1.ResourceName=J10.ResourceName
            and J1.success>=3
            and J2.success>=3
            and J3.success>=3
            and J4.success>=3
            and J5.success>=3
            and J6.success>=3
            and J7.success>=3
            and J8.success>=3
            and J9.success>=3
            and J10.success>=3
            and J1.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J2.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-2*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J3.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-3*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J4.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-4*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J5.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-5*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J6.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-6*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J7.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-7*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J8.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-8*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J9.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-9*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            and J10.colldate=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-10*60*60*24, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

the structure of the table is : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrE60.png)

Comment: Add a data sample which includes the source rowset and the requested rowset.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a table like this, I am assuming here that all that you have one record a day:

```sql
+------------+----------+-------+
|ResourceName|  colldate|success|
+------------+----------+-------+
|           a|2017-01-01|     10|
|           a|2017-01-02|     14|
|           a|2017-01-03|      9|
|           a|2017-01-04|     12|
|           a|2017-01-05|      8|
|           a|2017-01-06|      7|
|           a|2017-01-07|     13|
|           a|2017-01-08|     11|
|           a|2017-01-09|      5|
|           a|2017-01-10|      2|
|           a|2017-01-11|     16|
|           a|2017-01-12|     10|
|           a|2017-01-13|      9|
|           a|2017-01-14|     17|
|           a|2017-01-15|     12|
|           a|2017-01-16|     10|
|           a|2017-01-17|     13|
|           a|2017-01-18|      7|
|           a|2017-01-19|      9|
|           a|2017-01-20|      3|
+------------+----------+-------+
```

You can use a window function which will be a lot more efficient than 10 joins:

```sql
SELECT 
    *, 
    ( 
        sum(CAST(success >= 3 AS Int)) OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY ResourceName ORDER BY colldate ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
        ) 
    ) == 10 AS success_for_10days 
FROM J

+------------+----------+-------+------------------+
|ResourceName|  colldate|success|success_for_10days|
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+
|           a|2017-01-01|     10|             false|
|           a|2017-01-02|     14|             false|
|           a|2017-01-03|      9|             false|
|           a|2017-01-04|     12|             false|
|           a|2017-01-05|      8|             false|
|           a|2017-01-06|      7|             false|
|           a|2017-01-07|     13|             false|
|           a|2017-01-08|     11|             false|
|           a|2017-01-09|      5|             false|
|           a|2017-01-10|      2|             false|
|           a|2017-01-11|     16|             false|
|           a|2017-01-12|     10|             false|
|           a|2017-01-13|      9|             false|
|           a|2017-01-14|     17|             false|
|           a|2017-01-15|     12|             false|
|           a|2017-01-16|     10|             false|
|           a|2017-01-17|     13|             false|
|           a|2017-01-18|      7|             false|
|           a|2017-01-19|      9|             false|
|           a|2017-01-20|      3|              true|
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

And then filter on `success_for_10days`